# Has /usr/local/Library/Contributions/ been deprecated?

Tags: homebrew, bash-completion

For some time I've had a

```
/usr/local/Library/Contributions/
```

directory on my system and have been loading at least a `brew_bash_completion.sh` from it with

```
source $(brew --repository)/Library/Contributions/brew_bash_completion.sh
```

in my `.bash_profile`.

But suddenly I have no `/usr/local/Library/Contributions/` directory at all!

Has this directory been moved or deprecated by Homebrew? What is the current best way to get support for `brew` bash completion?

Answer (score 4):

The Homebrew completion script is at `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew` (or, more generally, `$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/brew`). This change was made on April 3rd in commit [edf000e](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/edf000e) when some parts of Homebrew were re-organized.

Comment: Yes, that's where I've got it now since `brew install bash-completion` just now in an attempt to fix this. But up until today I'd never had any trouble loading the earlier version. Where did it go; and where did `/usr/local/Library/Contributions/`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: It moved in commit edf000e a few days ago, when some parts of Homebrew were re-organized: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/edf000e

Comment: Actually I've now got `. $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion` (as suggested in by `brew info bash-completion`.

Comment: Ah, just so long as I didn't somehow inadvertently delete it myself. Could you add that to the answer?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Completions for bash don't require the bash-completion package (those are completions for other common programs); brew's bash completion script is still shipped with brew.